# Перебор массива char text1[]

Tags: java

Работает ли обычный `for`? Например поиск есть ли заглавные буквы.

```
public static boolean ABC( char text[]){
    for( char i="A"; i< text.length;i++ ){
        if(i>=65 && i<=90 ){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример кода с комментариями:

```
public static boolean ABC(char text[]){
    //Идем по всей строке text обращаясь по индексу
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        //Если i-тый символ text является заглавной буквой английского
        //алфавита, то мы сразу возвращаем true
        if(text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z'){
            return true;
        }
    }
    //Если мы не вышли из функции до этого момента
    //то заглавных букв найдено не было
    return false;
}
```

Я думаю сразу можно увидеть в чем у вас ошибки. И да перед `return true` если вам нужно, можете вставить вывод чего угодно. А в место `'A'` и `'Z'` вы можете написать `65` и `90` соответственно, но я думаю так намного понятней.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

Небольшое улучшение кода. Теперь он работает на символ любого языка:

```
public static boolean ABC(char text[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        //Воспользуемся функцией Character.isUpperCase, которая
        //возвращает true если символ в верхнем регистре (заглавная)
        //иначе false
        if(Character.isUpperCase(text[i])){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, делаю поиск находит только одну заглавную а не все которые там есть

Comment: @Mobsman если вам нужна функция, которая находит все заглавные буквы, то избавьтесь от `boolean` и всех `return`. В условии у вас написано `есть ли заглавные буквы` по этому эта функция как только найдет одну заглавную букву сразу возвращает `true`

Comment: не могу додумать если не нашел заглавных куда поставить вывод, если вне цикла то пишет всегда, если в цикле тоже пишет всегда

Comment: Если вам нужно вывести все заглавные буквы в тексте и при этом вернуть `true` если они были найдены иначе `false`, то сделайте в функции переменную `boolean isFInd = false` и в самом цикле если найдете заглавную букву, то присвойте `isFind = true`, а после цикла возвращаете `isFind`

Answer (score 0):

#### Спасибо [Павлу Ерикову](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/309995/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%95%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2) за совет по использованию `Character.isUpperCase(c)` , вот код:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Проверка
        System.out.println(ABC("Привет мир".toCharArray()));
        System.out.println(ABC("привет мир".toCharArray()));
        System.out.println(ABC("Hello word".toCharArray()));
        System.out.println(ABC("hello Word".toCharArray()));
        System.out.println(ABC("hello word".toCharArray()));
        
    }

    public static boolean ABC(char text[]){
          for (char c : text) 
                if(Character.isUpperCase(c))
                     return true;
          return false;
    }
```

Comment: 1. Зачем 2 раза `main` 2. А не проще тогда уж использовать функцию `Character.isUpperCase`, а не переводить в строчку, потом что-то там сравнивать

Comment: 1. Случайно нажал ctrl+ v 2. Благодарю, не знал, сейчас исправлю

Comment: Ну тогда ваш вариант уже не является улучшенной версией моего :)